# how to convert any integer to nearest whole number for graph

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have graph i want that graph it should show in whole number like 20 40 80 100 04 200 250 500 750 1000 like this so how to get this at run time if our result comes 75 then it should display 100 on graph line insted of 70 and like wise if there is

here is the code which i am getting the final like in my answer final max is 850 and i want that is should on graph max value 1000;

```
    int finalmax=(maxone>maxtwo)? maxone:maxtwo;

    finalmax=(finalmax>maxthree)?finalmax:maxthree;
```

Comment: Do you want to round to nearest hundred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take any number and round it to the nearest hundred by dividing it by 100 and rounding to the nearest integer and then multiplying by 100.

```
int i = 70;
float j = roundf(i / 100.0);  // j = 0.7 so rounds to 1
int result = j * 100; // result = 100
```

or...

```
int i = 312;
float j = roundf(i / 100.0);  // j = 3.12 so rounds to 3
int result = j * 100; // result = 300
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have static values you could use a code like this:

```
switch (value) {
    case (0)...(20):
        return 20;
        break;
    case (21)...(40):
        return 40;
        break;
    default:
        return 100;
        break;
}
```

with dynamic boundaries you should save your values in an Array and search for the first value greater or equal to your Number